# Network flow path using spanning tree protocol

Tags: networking, switch, stp

I have two machines, A and B, connected via switch S1(master) and s2(slave). I want to measure latency and identify packet flow path from machine A to Switch,switch to machine B. If the link between s1 and A gets failed then packet will flow via s2 and A link.

How to find a packet flow path using spanning tree protocol. Is there any commands in switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is pretty vague, because your question is too.  Drop a comment if you add info to your Q, and I'll do the same.

Most switches don't have a flow path tool per se.  So what you'll want to do is use the switch to determine which ports are blocked via STP.  That, coupled with your knowledge of the physical layout, will let you know which cables are actively being used for transmission.  So you shouldn't have a problem disconnecting those links to simulate failures for your tests.

On a cisco-style CLI, you'll want to use `show spanning-tree` to see STP info.  `show spanning-tree blockedports` will specifically list those ports being blocked by STP.